# How to link different object file with LLVM library?

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm, clang++

I am following the LLVM tutorial : [Kaleidoscope: Code generation to LLVM IR](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html), which will use LLVM libraries like LLVMContext, Module and so on. Different from the tutorial, I am trying to write the lexer, parser and code generator in different source file and link them into one executable file.
Here is my compile command on the Ubuntu 20.04:

> clang++ -g -O3 -I /home/therlf/LLVM/include -I ./ -I /home/therlf/LLVM_Temp/llvm/include `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all` ast/CallExprAST.o ast/NumberExprAST.o ast/PrototypeAST.o ast/FunctionAST.o ast/BinaryExprAST.o ast/VariableExprAST.o lexer/lexer.o logger/logger.o parser/parser.o main.cpp -o main

But I only get lots of "undefined error".
Here are some of them:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-2b71c8.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks
>
> /home/therlf/MyProject/tmp/ast/CallExprAST.cpp:6: undefined reference to `llvm::Module::getFunction(llvm::StringRef) const'
>
> /home/therlf/LLVM/include/llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h:1112: undefined reference to `llvm::Instruction::Instruction(llvm::Type*, unsigned int, llvm::Use*, unsigned int, llvm::Instruction*)'
>
> /usr/bin/ld: /home/therlf/LLVM/include/llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h:977: undefined reference to `llvm::VectorType::get(llvm::Type*, llvm::ElementCount)'

At first I thought it's including path's error. But when I **compiled and ran the source file in the tutorial successfully**, which is just a whole source file with everything packed into file, I knew the including path is nothing wrong.

I have searched for this question, and some blogs say that you should link them with `lld` and use the `-fuse-ld=lld` in the compile command. But I don't have `lld`, and the `clang++` doesn't know the argument `-fuse-ld`, which will report an error. The blog says that you should have `lld` as long as you have installed LLVM. In fact here are what I got: [LLVM tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0rB8.png)

And I know the `llvm-link` is used to link IR file, not the object file compiled from cpp source file.

Here is my LLVM version:

> 10.0.0svn

And here is my Makefile:

```
SOURCES = $(shell find ast kaleidoscope lexer logger parser  -name '*.cpp')
HEADERS = $(shell find ast kaleidoscope lexer logger parser -name '*.h')
OBJ = ${SOURCES:.cpp=.o}

CC = clang++
# -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11
CFLAGS = -g -O3 -I /home/therlf/LLVM/include -I ./ -I /home/therlf/LLVM_Temp/llvm/include
LLVMFLAGS = `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all`

.PHONY: main

main: main.cpp ${OBJ}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LLVMFLAGS} ${OBJ} $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -r ${OBJ}

%.o: %.cpp ${HEADERS}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${LLVMFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
```

In fact, I follow the project structure from the repository : [ghaiklor/llvm-kaleidoscope](https://github.com/ghaiklor/llvm-kaleidoscope) and the Makefile is nearly identical.

Sincerely thank you for your answers!

Comment: I have solved it by install lld and set it as default linker: )

Comment: If you solved your own question, best to post that as an answer rather than a comment. It's totally ok to do so and even encouraged.

Comment: @silvergasp Sorry, I just see this comment. Thank you for your advice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sloved this problem by exchanging my linker `ld` with linker `lld`.
You should install `lld` first by this command in ubuntu if you can't find it in the LLVM/tools directory like I did.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install lld
```

And then you can add `-fuse-ld=lld` to your compile command

or you can

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s /path/to/ld.lld /usr/bin/ld
```

This should work if everything goes well.

But I still can't figure out the reason behand this situation :-(

Comment: Probably better practice to use the command line flag `-fuse-ld=lld` on your CFLAGS than to symlink lld->ld